# Bypassing Proxy in KSoap 2 in Android app in ICS 4.0.4

Tags: android, proxy, ksoap2, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-ksoap2

I have an Android application which connects to an HTTPS connection via the HttpTransportSE class of KSOAP2.

As of ICS 4.0.4, several 3G operators have been pushing incorrect definitions (ie. proxy server ip as the requested domain in the header sent to our server) which means connections are blocked by our server (for our accreditation, we cannot disable this).

e.g. the Apache error is: Hostname  provided via SNI and hostname  provided via HTTP are different

Is there any way of bypassing the phones proxy 3g settings (from the APN) in an android app to make a direct connection? I've looked everywhere and cannot find any answer to this.

Given this error in ICS 4.0.4 and the number of phones migrating to this version, it would be nice to get this error fixed :)

thanks! :)

Comment: Hi You had any success on this. I'am also running with this issue @steve

Comment: In case it helps, this issue looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352383/android-scheme-http-not-registered-on-ics-4-0-4-w-proxy

Comment: Any luck? I know its been a while, but I'm looking for a solution for this as well.