# Adding problems through Rest API to Redmine

Tags: android, rest, redmine

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) supports REST API. It also provides a library for Java, but it is compatible with android> 2.2.
I need tips on how to write addition issues however, compatible with android should be on version 1.6.
Thank you in advance, sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the source code of the library, if available, and set the Android version to 1.6. Then all classes that are not supported, will be visible. Then you have to implement these classes.

Based on the 2.2+ limitation, I could guess that the limitation is the Http client that this library uses (i.e. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html).

Hope this helps!

In case you have any other specific problem, do not hesitate to ask us again!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was to checkout a copy of the [redmine-java-api](https://github.com/taskadapter/redmine-java-api) and modify it. This is what I ended up having to do:

1. Replace all references to JSONWriter with JSONStringer.
2. Replace all slf4j logging with android logging
3. Followed these answers to replace the encoding method https://stackoverflow.com/a/2533538, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8059544.
4. Followed this answer to replace the PoolingClientConnectionManager  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12045168
5. Follow this answer to replace the NaiveSLLFactory https://stackoverflow.com/a/7636810

Alternatively, If you look at this [issue](https://github.com/taskadapter/redmine-java-api/issues/49), another person has solved the problem.