# Working with android and redmine restapi to log time

Tags: android, json, redmine

i m working on a app that can log time using redmine.
for now i can receive the projects, but i have no idea about log the time.

there is a restapi of redmine, but i dont find any answers...:

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api

regards,
kai

Comment: How about clicking the Time Entries link

Comment: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_TimeEntries  it says how to log time to either project or issue right there..

Comment: of courde i saw this, but i dont know how to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow what the [redmine-java-api](https://github.com/taskadapter/redmine-java-api) does. Unfortunately the redmine-java-api doesn't work out of the box on android but it can be modified to do so. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16780268/1427295).

Alternatively follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3506039/1427295) answer on how to make a HTTP request and make a request by:

```
new RequestTask().execute("http://demo.redmine.org/time_entries.json");
```

Then, to make a POST request follow [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient) guide