# JSON with HttpClient error in Android

Tags: android, json, httpclient

I have some problems while working with JSON in Android, it gives me some error in log cat please help me what should i do, here is my code:

```
String feedUrl= "https://107.170.117.18:7000/infoes/";
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     context=this;

    infoListTask loaderTask = new infoListTask();
  loaderTask.execute();

}

private class infoListTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {


    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog= new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setTitle("Loading ...");
        dialog.show();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(feedUrl);

        try {
            HttpResponse response =client.execute(getRequest);
            StatusLine statusline= response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode= statusline.getStatusCode();

            if(statusCode != 200){

                return null;
            }

            InputStream jsonStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while((line= reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                builder.append(line);
            }

            String jsonData= builder.toString();

            Log.i("You json Data", jsonData);



        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
             //TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialog.dismiss();
        //videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }


}
```

and this is my log cat :

```
06-17 11:55:50.361: W/System.err(2224): javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
06-17 11:55:50.397: W/System.err(2224):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:146)
06-17 11:55:50.409: W/System.err(2224):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
06-17 11:55:50.413: W/System.err(2224):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:388)
06-17 11:55:50.413: W/System.err(2224):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
06-17 11:55:50.413: W/System.err(2224):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-17 11:55:50.413: W/System.err(2224):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-17 11:55:50.417: W/System.err(2224):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-17 11:55:50.417: W/System.err(2224):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-17 11:55:50.421: W/System.err(2224):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-17 11:55:50.421: W/System.err(2224):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-17 11:55:50.421: W/System.err(2224):     at com.amirhossein.test.MainActivity$infoListTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:78)
06-17 11:55:50.421: W/System.err(2224):     at com.amirhossein.test.MainActivity$infoListTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-17 11:55:50.421: W/System.err(2224):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-17 11:55:50.425: W/System.err(2224):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-17 11:55:50.425: W/System.err(2224):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-17 11:55:50.433: W/System.err(2224):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-17 11:55:50.437: W/System.err(2224):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-17 11:55:50.437: W/System.err(2224):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-17 11:55:50.449: W/EGL_genymotion(2224): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-17 11:55:50.529: W/EGL_genymotion(2224): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Answer (score 0):

See other questions for 'SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate':

[Android: Making Https Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622004/android-making-https-request)

[Safely fixing: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126372/safely-fixing-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-no-peer-certificate)